# Detect if input is a prime number in PHP - concerned with best practice code syntax

Tags: php, primes

I'm teaching my wife to code, so we made a simple prime-number detector.

We came up with this, but I'm wondering if there's a better / neater way. I particularly don't like the 0/1 switch for displaying the end statement.

```
//get n from URL
$n = $_GET['n'];

$j=2;
$prime=1;

while ($j<=($n/2)){

    if (is_int($n/$j)){ $prime=0;
        break;
    }

   $j++;

}

if ($prime==1) {echo "Yes! $n is a prime number";}
else {echo "No, $n is not a prime number";}
```

Comment: Probaly prime? http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-prob-prime.php``

Comment: The `gmp_prob_prime` function is fun :) http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmp-prob-prime.php

Comment: Damn, how many functions has PHP got?! Whilst, gmp_prob_prime is much neater, it does miss the point of teaching her to construct a function. I'm more concerned about the code syntax and if there's better way to set statements as true or false instead of the 0/1 switch.

Comment: @Mike generally yes, make it a function that returns a boolean. Then your `if` check just becomes `if(isPrime($number))` which reads _a lot_ more like a natural language

Comment: Your loop can check for `$j <= floor(sqrt($n))` (probably would pre-compute sqrt($n)`)

Comment: @lurker - can you offer a little more info on the maths of floor(sqrt($n) please - struggling to figure that out. Thanks

Comment: Why are you using 0 and 1? It would be more logical and semantically correct to use `true` and `false`. Makes it a lot easier to explain.

Comment: @MikeThrussell, yes, if `n = a * b` and `a > floor(sqrt(n))` then it will be necessarily true that `b <= floor(sqrt(n))` since `b = n/a`, so you will have already checked the other factor. You can try a few examples to see this to be the case. Thus, for divisibility, you only need to check factors up to `floor(sqrt(n))`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is always the neat and newbie friendly regular expressions way of finding prime numbers:

```
$n = $_GET['n'];
echo "$n is ", preg_match('/^1?$|^(11+?)\1+$/', str_repeat('1', $n))
    ? "not " : "", "a prime number", PHP_EOL;
```

No seriously, what I would suggest is that you tidy up your code a bit, so it gets easier to read:

- Remove unnecessary parentheses
- Rename `$prime` to `$isPrime`
- Change `$j++` into `$j = $j + 1`
- Add a quick check on 0, 1 which are not prime numbers

Like so:

```
// Get parameter 'n' from URL
$n = $_GET['n'];

if ($n <= 1) {
    $isPrime = false;
}
else {
    $isPrime = true;
    $j = 2;

    while ($j <= $n / 2) {
        if (is_int($n / $j)) {
            $isPrime = false;
            break;
        }
        $j = $j + 1;
    }
}

if ($isPrime) {
    echo "$n is a prime number";
}
else {
    echo "$n is not a prime number";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as a 'neater' way to display the end statement, you could just tidy it up with:

```
echo ($prime) ? "Yes! $n is a prime number" : "No, $n is not a prime number";
```

Also for readability you could use boolean true/false instead of 1 and 0's but that's really just your preference.

Comment: That's nice. So I would simply substitute 0 for false, 1 for true for improved readability?